# onEndReached not working in react-native flatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <FlatList style={styles.container}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    data={this.props.recieveLetter}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={extractKey}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    />
</View>
```

`onEndReached` is not called when I scrolling to the end and I can't get more data from the API.

Comment: try changing onEndReachedThreshold to 10

Answer (score 0):

`onEndReachedThreshold` needs to be a number between `0` and `1` to work correctly, so try setting it to `0.1` if you need a small threshold, or even `0.01`, and it should work in most cases.

However, from my testing in react native `v0.57.4`, `onEndReached` has an erratic behavior even then, sometimes it's not called when you scroll too quickly in Android, and if you are on iOS and the list does the bounce effect when reaching the end, it may be called several times. The most consistent way of triggering my end of list function was to make an end of list check myself, made possible using the props from ScrollView (which FlatLists accept). I did it using `onScroll` prop like this:

```
//Outside of the component
const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
    const paddingToBottom = 90; //Distance from the bottom you want it to trigger.
    return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
        contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
};

          //later, In my screen render
           <FlatList
                //other flatlist props, then...
                onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
                    if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
                        if (!this.state.gettingMoreList) {
                            this.setState({
                                gettingMoreList: true
                            }, () =>  {
                                this.loadMoreList(); //Set gettingMoreList false after finishing.
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }}
                scrollEventThrottle={1000}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me, add below line to FlatList:

```
onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore.bind(this)} //bind is important
```